# Create nested DDIC tables for JSON?

Tags: json, nested, abap, sap-gateway, sap-data-dictionary

I created a table "users" with user properties...
[image]

however, I wanted to have a complex/nested field called "address", but it seems tables can only be flat in abap dict tables... I can only use ".INCLUDE" to put the address fields flat into the table is that right?

I am just wondering, how I can then parse my complex json users object in an ABAP REPORT program and insert them into my ddict table...

```
REPORT zzzfz_ins_users.

*TYPES: ty_coord TYPE TABLE OF dec015 WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF address,
         country       TYPE char30,
         county        TYPE char30,
         city          TYPE char50,
         streetAddress TYPE string,
         latitude      TYPE dec015,
         longitude     TYPE  dec015,
         zipcode       TYPE int4,
       END OF address.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ls_user,
         mandt         TYPE mandt,
         id            TYPE num05_kk2,
         uuid          TYPE sysuuid_c36,
         firstName     TYPE char30,
         lastName      TYPE char30,
         fullName      TYPE char50,
         gender        TYPE char10,
         username      TYPE char30,
         email         TYPE ad_smtpadr,
         avatar        TYPE string,
         password      TYPE char50,
         birthdate     TYPE char10,
         registeredAt  TYPE char30,
         phone         TYPE char30,
         jobTitle      TYPE char50,
         jobType       TYPE char30,
         profileInfo   TYPE string,
         address       TYPE address,
*         country       TYPE address-city,
*         county        TYPE address-county,
*         city          TYPE address-city,
*         streetAddress TYPE address-streetaddress,
*         latitude      TYPE address-latitude,
*         longitude     TYPE address-longitude,
*         zipcode       TYPE address-zipcode,
*         maybe         TYPE  char30,


       END OF ls_user.

DATA lt_user TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ls_user WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.
DATA lv_dauer TYPE i.
*TYPES user_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ls_user WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.
DATA wa_user TYPE ls_user.



DATA(lv_json) =
`[{"id":1,"uuid":"3423e00f-b5c2-4f2c-bf88-baceca11c5f4","firstName":"Isabel",...}]
* JSON -> ABAP (iTab)
/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize(
  EXPORTING
    json             = lv_json
*    jsonx            =
    pretty_name      = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
*    assoc_arrays     =
*    assoc_arrays_opt =
*    name_mappings    =
*    conversion_exits =
*    hex_as_base64    =
  CHANGING
    data             = lt_user
).

*cl_demo_output=>write_data( lv_json ).
cl_demo_output=>write_data( lt_user[ 4 ] ).
*

cl_demo_output=>write_data( lt_user[ 5 ]-jobtitle ).
cl_demo_output=>display( lt_user[ 6 ]-profileinfo ).
*
DELETE FROM zalm_fs_users.
*
GET RUN TIME FIELD lv_dauer.
*
*
*INSERT zalm_fs_users FROM TABLE lt_user. "ACCEPTING DUPLICATE KEYS.
*
DATA: zalm_local_user TYPE zalm_fs_users.


*LOOP AT lt_user into DATA(lv_user).
*    zalm_local_user-avatar = lv_user-avatar.
**  INSERT zalm_fs_todos from lv_user. "Loop in Workarea
*ENDLOOP.
**
** loop at lt_todo assigning <fs_todo>.  "Loop mit Field-Symbol
**      INSERT zalm_fs_todos from <fs_todo>.
**endloop.
*
*
GET RUN TIME FIELD lv_dauer.
WRITE lv_dauer.
```

In debug it shows me address field as nested object:
[image]

And the output shows "kind of" nested internal table type address when printing it out:
[image]

and in the SEGW as well, there seems to exist the type "complex type", which is an object/structure without a primary key that you can insert into another structure (or table?, not sure about that)...
**How can I now insert my nested typeds into my users table? or is it not possible, so I would have to flatte my structures again?**

And btw, are the "entity types" that I create in SEGW different from the ddict table types? Because I assume the entity types (or instances of entities) are store in entity tables in some way.. are they a different concept than ddict tables?
I usually also create my entity types by importing them from ddict tables... so I am just wondering.

Comment: Reading JSON is to be done into a variable, you don't need DDIC at all. Storing complex data in relational database is not related to JSON. Relational database systems mean having several tables for storing data of various nature and cardinality. Please focus more, is the question more about JSON or data modeling or OData?

Comment: Could you share your example json data? Also specific to Odata concept you can make some research about 'get_expanded_entity'.

Comment: Its more about the "design" of relational tables in SAP DDIC I guess... I can obviously create arbitrary nested deep structures in an Abap Repost (program), and therefore easily put my json objects in those structures. But that does not count for SAP DDIC tables or structures. Therefore, I have to create several "flat" relational tables in the DDIC and build relations with foreign Keys... sorry for the confusion. I was just trying out things to kind of "push" my deep nested json into one table and that obviously does not work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to my problem.. (already some time ago, forgot about this thread ;)).
So to address the named "address" structure type included in your working area internal table on the DDIC physical table.. there is a column "GROUP" in the DDIC table, where you can give your includes a "group name". So in this case, it can be recognised as the named structure "address" type when you insert the data into the ddic table.
[image]